# How are complex arithmetic operators implemented in C?

Tags: c, complex-numbers

The ANSI C standard doesn't seem to explicitly specify any details on the API for complex arithmetic operators (+,-,*,/), though it seems that the implementation allows use of these primitives.  I'm wondering how this is possible, since C does not implement the concept of operator overloading?  My thought is that an implementation of the macros specifying the `complex` type will most likely utilize a built-in type which *does* permit such operations, but I then wonder how a complex number could permit the same range of values as, e.g., a single floating-point number (since it would have to somehow be represented as a pair of these, I would think its range would be cut in half)?

Am I thinking along the right lines, or am I way off on this one?

Comment: "the macros specifying the complex type " - what macros? `_Complex` is built into the language (and the macro `complex` is provided for readability)

Comment: So `_Complex` type does not need to be implemented by library, as well the arithmetic operators are built into the language, and not the library?  (as with any other built-in types?)

Comment: Yes that's right. The library has to have the specified library functions that take complex values (e.g.`cabs`)

Comment: I am guessing that is specified somewhere earlier on in the ANSI specification, on implementing the language?

Comment: The built-in types are in 6.2.5/11 , and library support in 7.3 (in C11)

Comment: IIRC, ANSI-C does not even have `_Complex`. That was introduced with C99, and became optional in C11. Both are ISO-standards - not sure if they actually have an ANSI-number (and I don't care, as much as US ppl care about DIN)

Comment: @Olaf C99 and C11 are ratified by ANSI.  C89 does not have any complex arithmetic at all so I assume OP means the latest standard ratified by ANSI

Comment: @Olaf, they have ANSI numbers, so referring to C89 as "ANSI-C" is quite ambiguous. And, AFAIR support for complex types was already optional for C99.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Well, normally, ANSI-C refers to C89 or C90. Although I anticipated it has an ANSI-number, my actual point was that it is just missleading for the reason given. (Sidenote: gcc uses `-ansi` as synonym for `c90`. Please note also, that ANSI is mostly relevant for the US; an international site should better refer to internation standards, if available. (Yes, I still use the term `ASCII`). For the question above, that was even more missleading as he refers to some macros.

Comment: @JensGustedt: C99 made `_Complex` mandatory (for whatever reason). This was (luckily) corrected with the C11 standard. The only option for complex numbers was support of ISO/IEC 60559 floating point complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C *does* have operator overloading -- even before the C89 standard, it overloaded operators like `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` for both integer and floating point operations.

C does not have *user defined* operator overloading -- so there are just the fixed set of overloads defined in the standard and no way to extend them.

C99 just extends the int/float overloading of operators to complex numbers.  There's still no way for a program to extend the overloading beyond that specified in the spec.

Comment: I had thought that operator overloading *was* a feature for the user (e.g. C++).  Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Since C99 complex types are an optional part of the C language, including support for all arithmetic operation.

And to answer your question about the representation, they are defined as pairs of a real and an imaginary part, just as one would expect.

Your reference to something like "ANSI C" is not well defined, because all ISO C standards usually get adopted by ANSI, too. So it is easier to refer to the different versions of C through their publication year, C89, C99 and C11.

Comment: Support for complex is mandatory for C99, but optional for C11. Only option (for both) is ISO/IEC 60559 compatibility.

Comment: To be a bit nitpicky: your "C89" should be "C90" (C89 is ANSI, C90 is ISO).

Comment: @Olaf, in C99, complex types are optional for freestanding environmements, so they cannot be considered to be part of the core language even then.

Comment: Found it myself. It is mandatory for a hosted environment (making it very well a standard feature for this), that's why `__STDC_NO_COMPLEX__` is missing. C11 made that optional for a hosted implementation, too and added the macro.